# Using handlebars template variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, templates, variables, handlebars.js

I would like to use a template variable Handlebars in javascript. Something like this:

```
<script>
var a = {{name}};
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: The values for these variables *come from* JavaScript, so I'm not really sure what you're asking for. Can you explain a use-case?

Comment: I load the template:
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#content").html(template({ name: "test" }));
In the template I can print {{name}} but I would like to user {{name}} in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Taking the cue from your explanatory comment, I'd say that you're thinking about this the wrong way. You want to do this:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#content").html(template({ name: "test" }));

var a = {{name}};
```

But what you should really do is:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var vals = { name: "test" };
$("#content").html(template(vals));

var a = vals.name;
```